# how to copy some csv file colums into another csv file with python?

Tags: python, csv

I have a 10 columns csv file and i would like to copy the first, the third and the seventh or another set of columns into a new csv file. Can you help me?
I have this code but i can't transform it to have my need.

```
<code>
def selection( fr=sys.stdin, fw=sys.stdout, delim=';'):
    my_reader = csv.reader(fr, delimiter=delim)
    my_writer = csv.writer(fw, delimiter=delim)
    to_write = [ col for col in zip(*my_reader) if col[0] == 'Nb_doc' ]
    my_writer.writerows(zip(*to_write))
    return
</code>
```

this code copy only the column named 'nb_doc'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will copy just the first, third, and seventh columns:

```
colNums = [0, 2, 6]
to_write = [ col for i, col in enumerate(zip(*my_reader)) if i in colNums ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could have a list of field names you'd like to select from and check if the first element of the column is in there:

```
fields = ["Nb_doc", "SomeOtherField1", "SomeOtherField2"]
```

Then, your list comprehension probably just needs to look like this:

```
to_write = [ col for col in zip(*my_reader) if col[0] in fields ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i would like to use column numbers instead  column names. Any other idea?